# iptables blocking all DNS queries

Tags: centos, iptables

I've been using CentOS 6 and recently no outgoing connection that uses a hostname works. This is probably due to iptables blocking all DNS queries, since there are no issues once the firewall is disabled.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Jul 20 17:40:16 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [672953:127627705]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6652:691635]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [661443:126705426]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7875:3320683]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [598139:125758733]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul 20 17:40:16 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Jul 20 17:40:16 2017
```

Is it possible that the above rules are the cause of this issue?

Output for `iptables -L -n -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 2493 packets, 403K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                         
  416 34155 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  697 64133 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   multiport dports 21,22,25,80,443,4082,4083,4084,4085,587
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   icmp type 0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   state NEW udp dpt:123
 1228 42752 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   icmp type 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   multiport dports 8443,2087,2086,10000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpts:5901:7000
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                           
    0     0            tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:22 state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:22 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 6 name: DEFAU                                                                                        LT side: source
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:22
    1   140 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:53

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 745K packets, 370M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                         
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        2          tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        0          tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
 7554  450K DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    4   240 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        48         tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *      <some_IP>             0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        4          tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        33         tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    1    40 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    1    40 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    2   120 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        54         tcp dpt:25
    4   240 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        53         tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        52         tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        49         tcp dpt:25
    4   240 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                        51         tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <some_IP>                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       <some_IP>            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   tcp dpt:25

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4522 packets, 880K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                                         
    3   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   multiport sports 25,587
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   icmp type 8
 1228 42752 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                                                                                                   icmp type 0
```

Comment: You are showing the chains of mangle table and all look empty. Can you post the output of `iptables -L -n -v` to check the filter table?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've updated the original post with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of this should probably be changed to:

> iptables blocking all DNS **responses**

as I believe your existing rules are blocking DNS *responses*, not *queries*.

The rules only allow UDP on the INPUT chain to destination port 123 on your server. You would also need to add a similar rule for UDP traffic but this time from **source** port 53 to allow DNS responses through from DNS servers that your server has sent queries to.

Something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```